# Read in Bézier curve from SVG file

Tags: graphics, string-manipulation, conversion, splines, svg-format

I am trying to do some calculation of some SVG file. After reading in with `Import["filename", "XML"]` and some easy operation, I can get the string of the Bézier curve, which is

```
"m", "10.297065,122.86673", "c", "-1.1327165,-2.9517", \
"-1.9996959,-5.44247", "-1.926621,-5.53505", "0.073075,-0.0926", \
"3.957119,-0.67937", "8.63121,-1.30398", "C", "51.148046,111.46463", \
"75.614452,102.94", "87.948536,91.308267", "L", "93.5,86.072926", \
"68.309017,86.036463", "c", "-13.855041,-0.02005", \
"-25.421756,0.336936", "-25.703812,0.793312", "-0.282056,0.456376", \
"1.914958,3.227403", "4.882253,6.157839", "l", "5.395081,5.328064", \
"-4.191269,3.372522", "-4.19127,3.37251", "-5.633788,-6.202247", \
"-5.633788,-6.202251", "-8.192543,4.262229", "c", \
"-4.505899,2.344227", "-8.454026,4.000749", "-8.773616,3.681159", \
"-0.31959,-0.31959", "-1.579212,-2.234924", "-2.79916,-4.256295", \
"l", "-2.218088,-3.675221", "7.125491,-3.411753", "c", \
"9.721447,-4.65472", "21.775439,-12.818376", "29.827634,-20.200987", \
"l", "6.702143,-6.144822", "4.047857,2.065063", "C", \
"61.178464,66.111369", "63,67.351969", "63,67.732472", "c", \
"0,0.380504", "-1.893694,2.621358", "-4.208208,4.979676", "L", \
"54.583584,77", "80.791792,77", "107,77", "l", "0,4.300463", "c", \
"0,3.602014", "-0.69025,5.119122", "-4.25,9.341089", "C", \
"92.980914,102.22798", "77.402299,111.67795", "57,118.39344", "c", \
"-11.332786,3.73023", "-30.101934,8.14519", "-39.071725,9.19063", \
"l", "-5.571726,0.64939", "-2.059484,-5.36673", "z"
```

How the data is managed is described in [this link](http://www.sitepoint.com/html5-svg-cubic-curves/); so, is there any good way to get a Bézier function out of this data?

Comment: Can you provide a link of your SVG file?

Comment: @Silvia https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3LNqmJl5ibIMXBpYjNfUG5kQ2c/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: You can open your SVG in Inkscape, export it as PDF and then `Import` the PDF in *Mathematica*.